# Is there a way to get actively used values for WI field using REST API?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

Right now I am getting all values for fields, I want to get only actively used options in work item templates. How do I do that? Please suggest.

{
"defaultValue": null,
"allowedValues": [
"1 - Extreme",
"1-Critical",
"2 - High",
"2-High",
"3 - Medium",
"3-Medium",
"4 - Low",
"4-Low",
"Extreme",
"High",
"Low",
"Medium"
],
"alwaysRequired": true,
"dependentFields": [],
"referenceName": "*****",
"name": "****",
"url": ""
}

Change Request /Bug /Defect template - I can see only four values for this field.

1-Critical
2-High
3-Medium
4-Low

Is there a way to get only these options from rest api?

Azure REST API Calls